# Переводить на нужный язык вне зависимости от языка пользователя

Tags: javascript

Как можно заставить gtranslate на странице переводить на нужный язык вне зависимости от того откуда пользователь.
То есть, чтобы любой пользователь зайдя на страницу сайт.ру/en видел сайт на английском языке, даже если пользователь русский.

Comment: по-моему, сложнее сделать, чтобы по адресу сайт.ру/en пользователь видел русский язык, если он русский)

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы если у пользователя в профиле выбран английский язык, он видел - все на английском переведенное гуглом.
При чем тут как сложнее сделать?